# Does a Javascript anonymous function remain visible? (Using a Java applet, a way to hide JS code)

Tags: javascript, applet

I'm writing an application using Javascript. I'm searching for a way to hide my code and I suppose I've found one, using Java Applet.

Anyway, I think that should be possible only if js *anonimous functions*' code doesn't remain accessible in any way after it's been evaluated.

```
(function(){...}).call(obj)
```

Applets can get a reference to the browser's window they are in, and call its `eval` method to evaluate js code:

```
// java code
JSObject window = JSObject.getWindow(this);
window.eval( "(function(){"
  + ...
  + "}).call("
  + thisObjectName
  + ")" );
```

Thus, I can change my js code, in the way that some functions, instead of having their code inside, call an applet function that asks the window to `eval` the original js function code, passing to the window an anonimous function, so that no function reference remains. Of course, js function must give to java function the name of the object (the `this`), and java function must compose the anonimous function adding a call to the `call(objectName)` method, to use the `this` reference properly.

```
MyJsClass.prototype.func = function() { ... };
```

becames:

```
MyJsClass.prototype.func = function() 
{
  ...
  myApplet.evalJsCode(thisObjectName);
  ...
};
```

---

**[UPDATE]** My idea was not good for 2 reasons

1. Java bytecode (.class) is easy to de-compile (thanks to [Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy))
2. The `window.eval` function called by the Applet is the very same you can override via javascript (thanks to [Yoshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/697154/yoshi))

Comment: Can't I just download your applet's .class file(s) and run them through a Java de-compiler, and then just look at the strings?

Comment: @Alessandro: Everything needs to be "visible", otherwise you wouldn't be able to run it.

Comment: With 'visible' I did mean you can decompile it and get the textual code. I don't think you can do the same with an exe file. I've seen some commercial apps written in Java: how is that possible if it's so easy to decompile them?

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered the following possibility?

```
​window.eval = function (code) {
  console.log('code');
};

eval('alert(1)');
```

Meaning, it takes almost no effort overriding the `eval` function.

Comment: What if I copy the eval function with another name?

Comment: The problem is the timing. You can never be sure that whenever you make your copy that `eval` has not already been overwritten.

Comment: Anyway, if bytecode is readable, my escamotage is unuseful. No Java application is closed source then?

Comment: And even then, a determined attacker could just recompile the browser JS parser to log everything that runs through it.

Comment: What if I compile an open source browser with my js code embedded and use that as my app?

Comment: Decmopile the applet.  Arguably that is easier than reverse engineering the browser.

Comment: DONE. Using Qt4, it's possible and even easy: to build an executable app, that contains a webkit-based Browser, with javascript. And, I suppose, no way to read html and scripts. Thanks Nokia.